# Custom return type (dynamic projection) for Spring CrudRepository save method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-jpa

I'm wondering if it is possible to define a custom return type for Spring's `CrudRepository` save method like in the following example for a find query method:

```
    <T> Optional<T> findById(Long id, Class<T> type);
```

[In the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic) I only found an example for dynamic projections with query methods.

I tried

```
    <T> T save(Foo entity, Class<T> type);
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object com.xyz.myproject.persistence.dao.FooDAO.save(com.xyz.myproject.persistence.model.Foo,java.lang.Class)! No property save found for type Foo!
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Try with  <T> T <T> save(.....

Comment: Try with just `T`

Comment: @JonathanJohx that is invalid syntax

Comment: @ayrton that is invalid syntax